# Java Icon Image Maximum File Size

Tags: java, image, swing, filesize, imageicon

I am working on a chess game on Java. I have been importing images onto Eclipse and then assigning them to ImageIcons, and then subsequently assigning these ImageIcons onto buttons to form a grid.

At one point three out of my four bishop images were not being assigned to their respective buttons and so I looked at the file size and it turns out that the sizes of the three images that weren't being assigned were ~1,100KB, ~1,200KB, and ~40KB. The image that was being assigned to the button was around 25KB. I thought this was odd (especially since all four images are very similar) so I exported the three problematic images in a lower resolution (all under 30KB), and then re-imported them into Eclipse. When I ran my program again they were assigned to the right buttons and everything ran smoothly again.

The buttons that I am using are all 75 x 75 pixels, and the pixels were the same for each image (75 x 75), so I am confused why this happened. I looked for any questions relating to this, but I could not find any. If anyone could help explain why this could happen to me that would be very helpful so I can avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: What file format do you use for the icons?

Comment: *"I thought this was odd (especially since all four images are very similar)"*  Using what logic system is a 1.1 MB image 'similar' to another of just 25 KB?  Why on Earth are the large ones so big?  One general tip is to use `ImageIO` to load the images - it will give a lot more ..feedback if there is a problem.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I was using .jpg files

Comment: @AndrewThompson I meant they were similar in the fact that the aesthetics of each photo are nearly identical, but for some reason the file size is dramatically different

Comment: *"I meant.."*  Yeah fine whatever, but can you answer my 2nd question and report back on the the result of using `ImageIO`?  And obviously those 'same pixel' images were encoded using ...very different formats.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am fairly new to Java and I don't know how to implement ImageIO instead of ImageIcon into my project. I tried to do the .setImageObserver that you commented below, but the piece didn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using `png` for transparent images and icons, `jpg` for non-transparent images - and only if compression artifacts don't matter ([lossless JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG) sadly isn't widely spread). `bmp` is one of the worst file formats out there if it comes to file size. As suggested by the others, load images in java with the `ImageIO` API:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream imageSource = Program.class.getResourceAsStream("bishop"); // may be a URL, File or ImageInputStream instead
        try {
            BufferedImage bishopImage = ImageIO.read(imageSource); // read image
            ImageIcon bishopIcon = new ImageIcon(bishopImage); // use adapter for Icon interface
            System.out.println(bishopIcon); // do something with it
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // read failed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've definitely loaded images much bigger than that into ImageIcons and other components, so I suspect that your issue is that when you are assigning the Image to the ImageIcon before the Image is fully loaded. You can use MediaTracker to help solve this problem. From ImageIcon:

```
/** * Loads an image into memory */ 
public static Image loadImage(String fn){ 
  try { 
    Image image=java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(fn);
    MediaTracker tracker=new MediaTracker(lblForFM); tracker.addImage(image,0); 
    tracker.waitForID(0);
    if (MediaTracker.COMPLETE != tracker.statusID(0,false)) throw new 
       IllegalStateException("Unable to load image from " + fn); 
    else return image; } catch ( InterruptedException e) { 
      throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while loading image from " + fn,e); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ssee also [`ImageIcon.setImageObserver(ImageObserver)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#setImageObserver-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-) (but I still prefer `ImageIO`, which blocks till the image is fully loaded).